# Insert Image to existing non-empty pdf

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to save an image into an existing pdf using apache PDFBOX,but my contents are getting deleted and i get blank document when I place the image on top of the pdf,Is there a solution to the problem?

My Code Looks like this.

```
    public class TestPdfImage {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
              //Loading an existing document
              File file = new File("...../mydoc.pdf");
              PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);

              //Retrieving the page
              PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);

              //Creating PDImageXObject object
              PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("...../sample.png",doc);

              //creating the PDPageContentStream object
              PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

              //Drawing the image in the PDF document
              contents.drawImage(pdImage, 70, 250);

              System.out.println("Image inserted");

              //Closing the PDPageContentStream object
              contents.close();     

              //Saving the document
              doc.save(".../sample.pdf");

              //Closing the document
              doc.close();

           }

    }
```

Comment: Please try the five parameter constructor `new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);` (this is a duplicate of some other question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the append-mode

```
//creating the PDPageContentStream object
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true);
```

**Edit**

TilmanHausherr mentioned

```
new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
```

[Thats why](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageContentStream.html#PDPageContentStream(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument,%20org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage,%20org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.AppendMode,%20boolean,%20boolean))

Comment: He should use the five parameter constructor.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yeah - You're right. I just looked up the api and now I know the reason ^^